# How to get color of a button with ripple drawable

Tags: android, drawable

I have variety of buttons and I would like to get their background color, getting background color in a color drawable is easy but it is not easy in ripple drawable, how can I manage to get background color from ripple drawable.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 RippleDrawable rippleDrawable = (RippleDrawable) button.getBackground();
 Drawable.ConstantState state = rippleDrawable.getConstantState();
 try {
     Field colorField = state.getClass().getDeclaredField("mColor");
     colorField.setAccessible(true);
     ColorStateList colorStateList = (ColorStateList) colorField.get(state);
     int rippleColor = colorStateList.getDefaultColor();
  } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: for default button background colour which looks to be something close to  #ffd6d7d7, your code returns #1f000000. How can I pick the right state, ie the state before the button is clicked? thx

Comment: @rockhammer you can try `ColorStateList.getColorForState`

Comment: thx for suggestion... took me a while to figure out how to work `.getState()` & `.getColorForState()`. Inserting `int[] statesOther = rippleDrawable.getState();` before `try` and a for loop within `try` to do `coloursOther[i] = colorStateList.getColorForState(new int[]{statesOther[i]}, 0);`, the entire `coloursOther[]` array and `rippleColor` return #1f000000. Then I thought may be that's coz I have this code in the `onClick()` so it would only show states relating to being clicked. Even when I put this code in `onCreate()` or `onWindowFocusChanged()`, I'm only getting #1f000000

Comment: I have the same issue, I'm getting the ripple effect's color, but what I want is the color of the AppCompatButton that has the RippleDrawable as its background. Maybe the color isn't stored in the RippleDrawable's ColorStateList, but where is it then..? If I set the background to null, then the button becomes transparent. So the color is somewhere in the RippleDrawable.

Comment: `getDefaultColor` returns a big number like 352321535. How can I convert this number in a color?

Comment: @capo11 `Color.parse("#"+Long.toHexString(352321535))`

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I found was to remove entries from the manifest of a newly minted app - particularly look at styles, themes and colours - compare older working apps with the new one to determine suspects.
The RippleDrawable then replaced itself with the ColorDrawable that it had been and .getColor() works again.

Answer (score -2):

please check following example for ripple effect in android..

http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/09/how-to-add-ripple-effect-to-android-button.html

Comment: I don't want a ripple animation, I would like get their background color