# How to get background color in MaterialButton in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-button, material-components, materialbutton

I have a layout:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
    ...
    app:checkedButton="@+id/favorite_color1"
    app:singleSelection="true">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/favorite_color1"
        ... />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/favorite_color2"
        ... />

</com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

in my fragment I can set background color in this way:

```kotlin
favorite_color1.setBackgroundColor(color)
```

A `MaterialButton` has a method `background` that returns a `RippleDrawable` and I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352945/how-to-get-color-of-a-button-with-ripple-drawable) but it doesn't work and it is out of date probably.

How Can I **get** background color for a `MaterialButton` programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `MaterialButton` the background color is defined by the **`app:backgroundTint`** attribute (not the `background` attribute).

The related method to set/get the background color are:

- `setBackgroundColor`
- `setBackgroundTintList`
- **`getBackgroundTintList`**

In your case you can use:

```
button.getBackgroundTintList()
```

This is a [**`ColorStateList`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList).
You can get the color of each state with the method: [**`colorStateList.getColorForState`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList#getColorForState(int[],%20int)).

For example:

```
textView.setTextColor(
        colorStateList!!.getColorForState(
      intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_enabled), 0))
```

or in java:

```
textView.setTextColor(colorStateList.getColorForState(
     new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled},0));
```

Just a note.
If you are using the `setBackgroundColor` method like `favorite_color1.setBackgroundColor(color)` the code above doesn't work.

You have to use the method `setBackgroundTintList`

```
favorite_color1.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color)))
```

Comment: ok but `button.getBackgroundTintList()` returns a `ColorStateList`, and then? I Can get the `defaultColor` but the value is a number like 352321535. Is this the right button background color? How Can I pass this number to a `Color` object?

Comment: @capo11 What is the final goal? How do you want to use the color?

Comment: the final goal is get the backgound color of the button and then change the background color of another view with the same color.

Comment: @capo11 if the other view works with a `ColorStateList` just use it. If it works with a single color use the method `colorStateList.getColorForState`. I've just updated the answer.

Comment: it doesn't work :( the method `colorStateList.getColorForState` always returns 0. I tried to change `android.R.attr` and the `defaultColor` parameter but the result is always 0.

Comment: @capo11 I tried it before writing the answer with the [standard style](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/res/color/mtrl_btn_bg_color_selector.xml#L19). The method `getColorForState` returns the color starting for a state. It depends also by the original color/selector defined in the button (There isn't the code in your question). Also check if the other view works with a color or a selector.

Comment: I have no doubt you tried it. I have not define a selector for my button, do I have to do it for my scope? The other View is a `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView`

Comment: @capo11 No, you don't need to define a selector. it is by default. In the ImageView what attribute are you trying to change?

Comment: my android running version is 29 and I'm using `com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06` library. Can is this the problem for our mismatch?

Comment: @ Gabriele Mariotti `val drawable = color_panel.background as GradientDrawable
        drawable.setColor(color)` and it works fine (because I change this color in another part of my app) but I don't think the problem is in the other view if the color value is 0. Maybe is the problem in how wh call `getColorForState`?

Comment: @capo11 Are you using `android:backgroud` in the layout or `button.setBackgroud(drawable)` ?

Comment: I use `button.setBackgroudColor(color)` only, with `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"`

Comment: @capo11 using button.setBackgroudColor(color) the code above doesn't work. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Yes!! It works! Thank you very much, you are a genius!